# Why doesn't the XML validate to the DTD

Tags: xml, validation, dtd

DTD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!ELEMENT language (definition, tu, tuv, seg) >
<!ELEMENT definition ANY >
<!ELEMENT tu ANY >
<!ELEMENT tuv ANY >
<!ELEMENT seg (#PCDATA) >
<!ATTLIST tu id CDATA #REQUIRED >
<!ATTLIST tuv lang CDATA #REQUIRED >
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE language SYSTEM "language.dtd">

<definition> # This is the line that seems to be the problem
    <tu id="webpage-title-text">
        <tuv lang="en">
            <seg>Demo CMS</seg>
        </tuv>
    </tu>
</definition>
```

The error message I get is:

> Document root element "definition", must match DOCTYPE root
>   "language". [4]

My Questions:

1. What is the reason so that the XML is not considered valid against
   the current DTD?
2. What I have missed in the DTD?
3. Could anyone
   recommend a good place to take as a resource of learning how to use
   DTDs, Schemas and etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<!DOCTYPE language SYSTEM "language.dtd">
```

to

```
<!DOCTYPE definition SYSTEM "language.dtd">
```

Comment: And could u provide a good place to learn this and that about DTDs and Schemas?

Comment: [Good site about XML Schema](http://www.xmlschemareference.com/), concerning DTD [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/) seems OK.